# React onDrop not firing only onDragOver and onDragLeave

Tags: reactjs, typescript, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop of files with React. I've got it from a tutorial and when clicking on the dropzone and adding files it works fine. It doesn't work when dragging the files over the dropzone.

I've added some console.logs to see what code is executed. It seems that only the onDragOver and onDragLeave seem to fire. The onDrop function never gets fires.

I also switch using the `react-dropzone` library but this got exactly the same result: onDrop was not firing.

I've tested with the latest version of Google Chrome and FireFox and both are not working.

```
import * as React from 'react'
const cloudIcon = require('../../../../images/cloud-computing.svg');


interface dropZoneProps {
  onFilesAdded: (event: any, array: any) => void
}

interface dropZoneState {
  highlight: boolean
}


export class DropzoneElem extends React.Component<dropZoneProps, dropZoneState> {
  constructor(props: dropZoneProps) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      highlight: false
    }
  }

  private fileInputRef = React.createRef<HTMLInputElement>()

  openFileDialog(event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    this.fileInputRef.current.click();
  }

  handleFileInputChange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    const files = event.target.files;
    const array = this.fileListToArray(files);
    this.props.onFilesAdded(event, array)
  }

  fileListToArray(list: FileList) {
    const array = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      array.push(list.item(i))
    }
    return array;
  }

  onDragOver(event: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('hit-1')
    this.setState({ highlight: true });
  }

  onDragLeave(event: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('hit-2')
    this.setState({ highlight: false });
  }

  handleOnDrop(event: React.DragEvent<HTMLDivElement>) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log('hit-3')

    const files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    const array = Array.from(files).map(file => { return file })

    this.props.onFilesAdded(event, array);
    this.setState({ highlight: false });
  }   

  render() {
    const dragClass = this.state.highlight ? 'dropzone highlight' : 'dropzone';

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <div className={dragClass} 
             onClick={event => this.openFileDialog(event)}
             style={{ cursor : 'pointer' }}
             onDragOver={event => this.onDragOver(event)}  
             onDragLeave={event => this.onDragLeave(event)}
             onDrop={event => this.handleOnDrop(event)} >
          <img src={cloudIcon} className='dropzone-icon' />
          <input ref={this.fileInputRef}
                 className='file-input'
                 type='file'
                 multiple
                 onChange={event => this.handleFileInputChange(event)}
          />
          <span>Upload Files</span>
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your code was successfully compiled? When I tried it, I had a few complained from the compiler